# Android How To Read JNI Core Dump Files

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm coding JNI application.  Logcat indicates that log files exist data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt
Also stuff in system tombstones. When I access the Samsung Infuse as media device I don't see any such files.  In fact I don't see my application data files either?  Where are they, I do see other application packages but not much under data period. Here is what I see in logcat:

dumpstate /data/log/dumpstate_app_native.txt
copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt

I did search on device as media device for *.txt and found nothing.

Answer (score 11):

You won't be able to read the tombstone files unless you are using an emulator or a rooted phone.
Logcat does print out the tombstone at debug level (it's that big core dump right before the "copying tombstone" message).  There should be a section that looks something like this:

```
01-18 16:28:04.334 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :  scr 80000012
01-18 16:28:04.334 16759 16759 I DEBUG   : 
01-18 16:28:04.384 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :          #00  pc 00007f84  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/myjnilib.so
01-18 16:28:04.384 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :          #01  pc 00008f80  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/myjnilib.so
01-18 16:28:04.394 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :          #02  pc 00002c6a  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/myjnilib.so
01-18 16:28:04.394 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :          #03  pc 00002ea8  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/myjnilib.so
01-18 16:28:04.394 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :          #04  pc 00003178  /data/data/com.myapp/lib/myjnilib.so
01-18 16:28:04.394 16759 16759 I DEBUG   :          #05  pc 00011e74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
...
```

This is the abbreviated stacktrace.  You'll need to use the addr2line tool in the NDK to determine the function, file and line number that those hex addresses refer to.  On my OSX system, the command to get the first line of the stacktrace looks like this:

```
/opt/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -f -e myJNIproject/obj/local/armeabi/myjnilib.so 0x00007f84
```

where *myJNIproject/obj/local/armeabi/myjnilib.so* is the version of *myjnilib.so* that contains line number information.

Comment: There's also `ndk-stack`, which is included in the ndk

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this link http://bytesthink.com/blog/?p=133

just make sure you have the right symbols sync with tombstone collected.