# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a weird error and I can't find where it comes from. The only thing that appears in the logcat is :

`01-10 17:07:10.665: A/libc(20449): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)`

I don't get this error right away when I run my app, I get it after a random amount of time (something between 1 min to 5 min). I'm unable to reproduce this error, it seems random and since there are no other informations it's hard to debug. I tried to add some log informations to my library but I still can't say where the crash occurs.

I ran the same app x times and I got different SIGSEGV address (sometimes it was the same address as before :

`01-10 17:29:04.650: A/libc(21588): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x6c707063 (code=1)`

`01-10 17:25:55.165: A/libc(21473): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0069004c (code=1)`

`01-10 17:11:58.780: A/libc(20742): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)`

`01-10 17:00:02.010: A/libc(20160): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000018 (code=1)`

My app is using a c++ library that has a NetworkThread that receives updates from a server. On the Java side there's a WorkerThread that check is there's new updates from the NetworkThread and if there's new updates it notifies all the listeners. I also have a LocationSpotter (on the Java side) that makes some JNI calls when the location is updated.

Is there a way to debug this or to use the addresses I got from the SIGSEGV to debug the app ? Also I'm using a shared JavaVM object for some methods to retrieve the current JNIEnv (and call AttachCurrentThread). Is that thread safe ?

I noticed that I still receive updates from the NetworkThread after I got the SIGSEGV error (before the app actually crashes). That means the NetworkThread is probably working.

I also noticed a line that could be the source of my problem (in the notifyAll method) because the last message printed before SIGSEGV is "notifyAll1" :

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
    try {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "notifyAll1");
        if (listeners.at(i) == NULL)
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "LISTENER NULL");


        listeners.at(i)->update(u); // <- This line is a potential suspect
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "notifyAll2");
```

The logcat :

```
01-10 17:07:10.665: I/FROM C++(20449): notifyAll1
01-10 17:07:10.665: A/libc(20449): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

I tried then to print a log in the first line of each listener's `update` method but none of them is printed (which is really weird I think).

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add the related tombstone file from /data/tombstones dir if one is created after your crash?

Comment: I couldn't find a tombstone file. I tried to go under DDMS perspective -> File Explorer -> data -> data -> (Your Package) -> files -> (Your File) but there was nothing... I tried that on the phone as well but no more results

Comment: By the way do you know why there's nothing under the data directory on my phone ? Should I root my phone to be able to read the tombstone files ? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8921133/1304830)

Comment: Fundamentally, you are dereference an invalid pointer, probably either in your code by handing one to system library code, or much less likely triggering a platform bug.  The primary thing you want to find is a native stack dump of the crash, any chance that was already in your logcat?.  The top level /data directory is not accessible on a secured device, but you may be able to cd to a specific directory underneath from the adb shell.  Or you may be able to replicate the problem on an emulator, where the adb shell already is root.

Comment: How did you enable exceptions in your native code? Which STL do you use?

Answer (score 5):

Most of time Fatal signal error occur when you are trying to access any object which is not created at that time. So check them properly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should rewrite the **notifyAll** loop like this:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
  try {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "notifyAll1 i=%u", i);
    auto listener = *listeners.at(i);

    if (&listener == NULL) {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "LISTENER NULL");
    }
    else {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "notifyAll2 : listener[%u] at %p", i, &listener);
      listener.update(u);
    }
```

- in your original code, the check was only printing to log, but **update()** would still fail ([@Robin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153396/robin) noticed this)
- in your original code, a **listener** could get invalidated NULL between check and **update()**
- even after the change above, **update()** could crash if the listener object pointed to by **listeners.at(i)** becomes invalid.

But it's possible that the crash happens because of exception handling. You did not reveal the **catch(...)** code, so I cannot speak about this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be obvious

```
if (listeners.at(i) == NULL)
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "LISTENER NULL");


        listeners.at(i)->update(u); // <- This line is a potential suspect
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "notifyAll2");
```

should be

```
if (listeners.at(i) == NULL) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "LISTENER NULL");
} else {
    listeners.at(i)->update(u); // <- This line is a potential suspect
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "FROM C++", "notifyAll2");
}
```